# Session leak on spanner insert from cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to insert data into spanner through cloud function, using post request. I thing that I'm doing everything as described in the documentation, and i just can't understand what causes the next error:

`"Error: 1 session leak(s) detected.
    at _requests.onIdle.then (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/spanner/build/src/session-pool.js:193:25)
    at <anonymous>"`

And there is my cloud function

```
const {Spanner} = require('@google-cloud/spanner');

module.exports.http = (req, res) => {
  const projectId = 'project-id';
  const instanceId = 'instance-id';
  const databaseId = 'database-id';

  const spanner = new Spanner({
    projectId: projectId,
  });

  const instance = spanner.instance(instanceId);
  const database = instance.database(databaseId);

  let sqlResponse = "";

  database.runTransaction(async (err, transaction) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({message: err, requestBody: req.body}));
      return;
    }
    try {
      const data = req.body;
      const [rowCount] = await transaction.runUpdate({
        sql:
          'INSERT Feedbacks (age, comment, gender, rating) VALUES (@age, @comment, @gender, @rating)', 
        params: {
          age: data.age.toString(),
          comment: data.comment,
          gender: data.gender,
          rating: data.rating.toString(),
        },
      });
      sqlResponse = 'Successfully inserted ' + rowCount + ' record into the Feedbacks table.';
      await transaction.commit();
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({message: sqlResponse, requestBody: req.body}));
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({message: err, requestBody: req.body}));
    } finally {
      database.close();
    }
  });

};
```

Comment: I think maybe you want to use `database.runTransactionAsync` to get a promise that will be used to determine when it's OK to terminate the function.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your error using your code, I was able to insert the first time correctly and the second time I got the same error, BUT, I was trying to to insert the same data and even though on the logs appear a leak error, on the response message appears this -> "{"message":{"code":6,"metadata":{"_internal_repr":{"grpc-server-stats-bin":[{"type":"Buffer","data":[0,0,109,114,159,29,0,0,0,0]}]},"flags":0},"details":"Row [primary-key] in table Feedbacks already exists"},"requestBody":{}}"  which basically means that you are trying insert a row with a primary key that already exists.

Comment: To fix this, whenever you want to update a row use a query similar to this: 'UPDATE Feedbacks SET comment=@comment , gender=@gender, rating=@rating WHERE age=@age'   ///// (I used "age" as primary key on my case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to be correct. As noted by @Mayeru in the comments for your question, the first thing to confirm is that you're inserting a new record with a unique value specified for the column that is your table's [primary key](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-and-data-model#primary_keys) column.

Another possibility that could be causing the issue you are encountering is that you are trying to test the function using the "Testing" UI of the Cloud Console's Cloud Functions > "Function details" section. If so then you may be either using an empty request body or a malformed request body when you click the "Test the function" button. In the "Triggering event" textarea that appears above the "Test the function" button, make sure you have entered a valid JSON request body which includes the elements and values that your INSERT statement expects.

For example a "Triggering event" JSON request body like the following should work:

```
{"singerId":"1001","firstName":"Test","lastName":"Singer"}
```

Using the following "nodeInsert" function that's similar to the code you've shared:

```
const {Spanner} = require('@google-cloud/spanner');

module.exports.nodeInsert = (req, res) => {

  const projectId = 'my-project';
  const instanceId = 'my-instance';
  const databaseId = 'my-database';

  const spanner = new Spanner({
    projectId: projectId,
  });

  const instance = spanner.instance(instanceId);
  const database = instance.database(databaseId);

  let sqlResponse = "";

  database.runTransaction(async (err, transaction) => {
    if (err) {
      res
        .status(500)
        .send(JSON.stringify({message: err, requestBody: req.body}));
      transaction.end();
      console.error('Transaction terminated.');
      return;
    }
    try {
      const data = req.body;
      const parsedSingerId = parseInt(data.singerId, 10);
      const [rowCount] = await transaction.runUpdate({
        sql:
          'INSERT Singers (SingerId, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (@singerId, @firstName, @lastName)', 
        params: {
          singerId: parsedSingerId,
          firstName: data.firstName,
          lastName: data.lastName,
        },
      });
      sqlResponse = 'Successfully inserted ' + rowCount + ' record into the Singers table.';
      await transaction.commit();
      res
        .status(200)
        .send(JSON.stringify({message: sqlResponse, requestBody: req.body}));
    } catch (err) {
      res
        .status(500)
        .send(JSON.stringify({message: err, requestBody: req.body}));
      transaction.end();
      console.error('Transaction terminated.');
    } finally {
      database.close();
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Managed to solve this problem by myself just before you posted this suggestion. Can't remember for sure what was the solving part, but probably as you suggest, the main reason was that i didn't insert a value for primary key(assumed that spanner would manage and autoincrement it by itself like the sql databases do). Going from there into error catching block, sessions leaked due to missing transaction.end();.